# ListView adapter getView called twice with null convertView on Nexus device

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, nexus-5

I've got a strange situation here.

There's a list view with a custom adapter. The view has a few different item types which are correctly used in `getViewItemType`. On just about every device and supported OS the `getView` method in the adapter is called without any weird behavior.

I know `getView` can be called many times and that isn't the issue. On a Nexus 5 and Nexus 6, however, getView is called twice for the same item type and passes a `convertView` of `null`.

The result is we end up creating two views for the same row in the list. It seems that one will actually get attached or added to the listview while the other isn't.

Any suggestions, or tips that might be causing this?

Comment: How do you know called twice for same item?

Comment: have you correctly overriden `getViewTypeCount()`??

Comment: I don't know if this will work but can you make your fragment a singleton?

Comment: check count of notifyDataSetChanged() ...

Comment: @Xcihnegn I ran the app with a debugger. It stopped on my breakpoint in getView multiple times (as expected) but two of the stops for the item passed null convertViews. It is a very small list, only four rows, each a different item type. They all show on the screen easily.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you know called twice for same item?

`I ran the app with a debugger. It stopped on my breakpoint in getView multiple times (as expected) but two of the stops for the item passed null convertViews. It is a very small list, only four rows, each a different item type. They all show on the screen easily`

> You should check the `position` in `getView()` to make sure if called twice.

I suppose not because that the first time of each item view(convertView) always null, then you need `inflate` the view with item view layout and return it. While next time show the same view(even though for different item), the `convertView` will be not null, but you still need set views with value that according to the item position.

Hope you got!

Comment: @Sababado do you agree this answer?